# displaying a report in server using report viewer VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, report-viewer2010

We hosted new website, in that I created 3 reports using asp.net
 MS-report (report viewer).

I published this locally and it is working great, but same thing I copied to server now its not displaying the report and it's asking for authentication. After providing username and password, it's simply showing a blank page.

And also manually I
 transferred all **.rdlc** files into report folder with I copied data set
 to application folder.

And here is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433 -->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="20"/>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, ulture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            </assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =databasename; User Id = user; Password = pwd;" />
        <add name="iCAMSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </handlers>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I kept all **.dll** in `bin`, for example:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
```

and reports(.rdlc) in report folder

Please any one can help me, I tried lot but i don't know where I am
 missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following in your example:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" 
        verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" 
        type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" 
        preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
```

Comment: <handlers><add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/></handlers>

Comment: Please do not post that code as comment. Edit your answer and add code there, then delete your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pati, but this issue i solved long back ago by deploying the project(previously took published project data) & installing report viewer supporting files in server after this my problem was solved.